# 開発環境用 Windows を VirtualBox 上に構築するにあたって必要なライセンス・契約は？

Tags: windows, virtualbox

やりたいこと: 開発環境用 Windows (Windows10 がいいと考えています）を、 VirtualBox 上で構築できたら嬉しいと考えました。

ホストPCは Mac で、 Windows の PC もライセンスも特に持っていない状態です。

次の条件があった時に、上記やりたいことを満たすために必要なライセンス・契約の一覧は何になりますか？

- 研究機関に所属しているわけではない（アカデミックライセンスなどは利用できない）
- 90 日などの制約がないライセンスが良い

Comment: 一応ですが、大学など研究機関に所属していたりはしないですか？場合によってWindowsはタダで手に入るので。

Comment: @packet0 一般企業所属です。。

Comment: Vagrantで[Windowsのイメージ](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=windows)がありますから、それを使えばいいのでは？確か１ヶ月くらいはライセンス不要なはず。VMだから毎回作り直しても大した手間じゃないですね。

Comment: Web開発におけるIEの検証用であれば[各バージョンのVMが無償で提供されています](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)が、Windowsアプリケーションの開発・検証環境としてはMSDNサブスクリプションを契約するか、普通にWindowsを購入する形になるのではないでしょうか。何かを購入、というのはそういう話ですか？

Comment: @KenjiNoguchi atlas で公開されているイメージは、 atlas ユーザーが勝手に作成、アップロードされたもの、という理解をしています(間違ってるかもしれないです)。仮に私の理解が正しいとすると、それを本当に使っていいのか、と不安になります。

Comment: @unarist msdn サブスクリプションが何なのかを理解していないです。今回の質問は、率直に、「なんか諸々の開発で使える Windows が欲しくなった」が動機です。このやりたいことを満たすためには、少なくともライセンス(と、いうのでしょうか？)を購入する必要があるのでは、また、他に何か制約があるかもしれない、と思ったため、「何かを購入」としました。

Comment: かつてMSは公式にVagrantのイメージを提供していたことがありましたので、参考までに書きました。

Answer (score 2):

個人で、あるいは小規模なチーム等で利用すると仮定した場合

スペックに十分な余裕があるMac上のVirtualBoxでWindows 10の正規ライセンスの仮想マシンを実行したいのであれば、 **有効なWindowsのライセンスを用意** すればいいでしょう。

ライセンスは量販店等の店頭や通販などで販売されている他、[Microsoftのサイト](https://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msjp/ja_JP/pdp/Windows-10-Pro/productID.5073993800)から即購入することも可能です。

VMで利用するのであればDL版でいいでしょう。ISOイメージが入手できるので、これをVirtualBoxで読み込めばセットアップが可能です。

(Windows 10のISOは[こちらからDL](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/software-download/windows10ISO)することも可能です)

Comment: 上記ISOはお試し的に（インストール中にライセンス入力を飛ばせるので多分公認）使えるので、ライセンスをお買いになる前に試してみるのもいいかもしれません。しばらくするとライセンス買えと言ってきますが、昔と違って全く使えなくなることは無いのです。あとライセンスは量販店の方がオンラインより2000円くらい安方気がします（おまけに円盤も付いてきます）。

Comment: ですね。お試しにもいいと思います。店頭でもUSBもディスクもない販売形態ってなかったでしたっけ（？）